# Different domains, different languages, same content, 1 robots.txt

Tags: robots.txt

I'm in this situation:

Domains:

```
www.example.com
www.example.it
```

that point at the same content in different languages. E.g.:

```
www.example.com/audi-car.html
www.example.it/audi-auto.html
```

and I have **only one robots.txt** in the root domains.

My question is: How can set my robots.txt to disallow crawling of `www.example.it` to all bots coming from `www.example.com` and reverse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write different robots.txt for each domain and use .htaccess to redirect robots.txt request based on host from where the request came:

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
    RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$  /robots-com.txt [L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.it$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
    RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$  /robots-it.txt [L]
```

Make sure that `RewriteEngine On` is placed on top and mod_rewrite enabled.